# Right verb(s) to welcome the guests at the door

Tags: verbs

When we have guests at the door, we welcome them. Which verb can show this action more properly, **greet** or **receive**?

Say:

> I ***greet*** Mr. X and his family at the door.

Or

> I ***receive*** Mr.X and his family at the door.

Which sentence looks more proper? Or Can we use both of them interchangeably?

Comment: You could greet or welcome guests in an informal setting.  Receive is usually reserved for very formal occasions like weddings or funerals.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know welcome is also a verb, and proper words for formal and informal words.

Comment: If anyone feels like writing this up as a proper answer, you're welcome to do so.  :-)  I just didn't feel comfortable leaving that short a message as an answer, and I don't have time for a longer version.  I'm glad it was helpful superuser.

Answer (score 3):

'Receive' is terribly formal and is used/seen only in the context of weddings, and state occasions.

In general, people 'greet' or 'welcome' guests.